# In a contract what is the difference between indemnify and defend?

Tags: contract-law, legal-terms

In a contract what is the difference between indemnify and defend? I often see them used together though I believe there is a subtle difference. If party x is to indemnify party y then x can't sue y. But if y gets in trouble then x will pay for the lawyers to defend y and that's what "defend". Do I understand correctly or what is the difference? A simple example illustrating the difference between indemnify and defend would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, if party *X* agrees to indemnify party *Y* for damage *Z*, then *X* is only agreeing to pay *Y* for realized damages *Z*.

Example: I agree to print something you wrote about about Acme.  In exchange, you agree to indemnify and defend me against any defamation claims by Acme.  Acme sues me for defamation.

1. Since you agreed to *defend* me, you have to provide a legal defense against Acme's lawsuit.  If you didn't agree to indemnify me, and Acme wins a judgment, you wouldn't be obligated to pay the judgment.
2. If you only agreed to *indemnify* me, you could choose to let the lawsuit run its course without providing any legal defense.  Indemnification only requires you to pay any judgment Acme might win.

Comment: The second instance creates a moral hazard for party X: it is in Y's interest to concede Z's claim, it may be in X's interest to defend it. This is why they usually go together.

Comment: @DaleM - I think I could come up with a moral hazard scenario, but *in general* I don't see how it would be in *Y*'s *interest* to concede a third-party claim.  In the example given: With no defense I am adjudged a libeler, even though I don't have to pay the associated damages.  I'm having trouble imagining people who have an interest in being so branded.

Comment: possibly not for libel but being negligent is far less of a slur

Comment: In practice, there are contractual agreements to "indemnify" only, and contractual agreements to "indemnify and defend", but almost never a contractual agreement to "defend" but not indemnify. But, the scope of the duty to "defend" when there is a duty to "indemnify and defend" is broader than the duty to indemnify (since the legal basis for alleged liability is usually less clear than the legal basis for actually imposing liability), so it isn't uncommon to "defend under a reservation of rights" to contest the duty to indemnify when a contract creates a duty to "indemnify and defend".

Comment: @ohwilleke - Good explanation.  A common example might be liability insurance:  I have seen cases in which an insurer mounts a defense for the insured (as required under their contract) but, since they reserve their rights, when things get tough they may sue for a declaratory judgment on various theories that they do not have an obligation to defend under the contract, or pay a resulting liability.

Comment: If X has agreed to defend Y, and Y invokes the clause, does Y have carte blanche to hire the most expensive attorneys they can find and sock X with the bill, or does X have the right to manage the defense or at least make basic decisions on how it will unfold? E.g. "Hey, I'm the one defending here, remember! I said we are going to use the Chewbacca Defense! If you want something else, release me from my contract to defend you and go develop and pay for your own strategy."

Comment: @RobertColumbia: As [ohwilleke also noted](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/18985/in-a-contract-what-is-the-difference-between-indemnify-and-defend/18991?noredirect=1#comment33259_18991), I have only seen scenarios in which the party who has agreed to defend is also on the hook for damages, so *Y* has little practical claim on how *X* goes about the defense, unless *X* is doing such an unreasonable job (which would ultimately have to be established in a separate trial) as to imperil *Y*.