# Difference between protect and defend in a contract?

Tags: contract-law

From this [Maintenance Agreement](https://www.slamdot.com/maintenance):

> Customer represents to Slamdot and unconditionally guarantees that any
>   elements of text, graphics, photos, designs, trademarks, or other
>   artwork furnished to Slamdot are owned by Customer, or that Customer
>   has permission from the rightful owner to use each of these elements,
>   and will hold harmless, protect, and defend Slamdot and its
>   subcontractors from any claim or suit arising from the use of such
>   elements furnished by Customer.

What's the difference between defend and protect as the relate to litigation? Can someone provide a simple example with a shorter contract?

I've also seen "save" thrown into the mix.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In a contract what is the difference between indemnify and defend?](https://law.stackexchange.com/q/18985/10)

Comment: FWIW, "hold harmless, protect and defend" is quite unconventional language. While "hold harmless" and "defend" are commonplace, "protect" is quite unusual to see in this context.

Comment: I've also seen "save" used in the context.

Answer (score 1):

In the context of that clause. I believe protect and defend means the same thing. The clause just uses both words to increase clarity of the meaning conveyed.

Comment: I agree. As used it seems to me that *defend* is a legal term of art, as in plaintiff vs defendant. *Protect* could apply to extra-judicial activity that might not be technically legal defense.